# Flutter's CircularProgressIndicator stops animation when navigated

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-animation

I have a `CircularProgressIndicator` in page.
When I navigate to that page like below, the indicator stops animation at first few frames.

```dart
final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
navigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const Page()));
```

[image: indicator_stops_animation]

This is Page class code. As you can see, there is no heavy work that will stop main Isolate.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State<Page> {
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Title'),
        ),
        body: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: const Text('Finish'),
    );
  }
}
```

Why this animation stop happens?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
As mentioned in the related question, this happens when using `MaterialPageRoute`.
I did some reaserch and found that [ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/page_transitions_theme.dart)
is used as default theme's `pageTransitionsTheme`. The comment of this class's `allowSnapshotting` says the reason.

> /// When this value is true, zoom page transitions will snapshot the entering and
> /// exiting routes. These snapshots are then animated in place of the underlying
> /// widgets to improve performance of the transition.
> ///
> /// Generally this means that animations that occur on the entering/exiting route
> /// while the route animation plays may appear frozen - unless they are a hero
> /// animation or something that is drawn in a separate overlay.

As mentioned above, set this property to false resolve this issue.
Hope this helps someone.